# Use of unresolved identifier when testing a public class

Tags: swift, geohashing

I’m unable to unit my class because Xcode doesn’t see my main class under test target.

My swift module is defined as public

```
public class Geohash {
    public static func encodeGeoHash(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, precision: Int = 12) -> String {
```

but under my tests target I can’t see the symbol,

```
class GeohashTests: XCTestCase {
    func testEncode() {
        Geohash // /Users/maximveksler/Developer/GeohashKit/GeohashKitTests/GeohashTests.swift:13:9: Use of unresolved identifier 'Geohash'
    }
}
```

My tests target does not include Geohash.swift

[image]

The project is at  https://github.com/maximveksler/GeohashKit/blob/master/GeohashKitTests/GeohashTests.swift#L13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test file add below line:

```
import GeohashKit
```

Test part of project is separate module so you need to import your app module to test class files in order to access its classes.

Comment: Where can I learn more information about this? What is the scope of a module compared to a “framework” ?

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html